# How do I make a counter that counts the amount of active inputs

Tags: programming

I want to make a direction guide using green, yellow and red LEDs. The lights need to change when ever the active input<sup>1</sup> reaches a set value, for example:

- Green when the value is lower than 12;
- Yellow when the value is higher than 11 and lower than 20;
- Red when its higher than 19.

I've been searching for a few days but I couldn't find any references.

---

<sup>1</sup> By *active inputs* I mean, a series of buttons being pressed at the same time, if there is 29 buttons then when less then 12 of them is pressed the green light would be turned on.

Comment: The reference you would look for would be something on the C or C++ language. That would describe the basic structure of "conditional statements" like `if (x < 5) {...}` and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by "active input"? What kind of input, and what does the value indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
const int BUTTON_MAX = 29;
const int button[BUTTON_MAX] = { 5, 6, 7, ... };
const int GREEN_LED = 2;
const int YELLOW_LED = 3;
const int RED_LED = 4;
int current_led;

void setup()
{
   // Setup inputs (buttons)
   for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_MAX; i++) pinMode(button[i], INPUT_PULLUP);

   // Setup outputs (led)
   pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(YELLOW_LED, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);

   // Initial state
   current_led = GREEN_LED;
   digitalWrite(GREEN_LED, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);
   digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
   // Count number of active buttons
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_MAX; i++) count += digitalRead(button[i]);

   // Map number of active buttons to led
   int new_led;
   if (count < 12) 
      new_led = GREEN_LED;
   else if (count < 20) 
      new_led = YELLOW_LED;
   else 
      new_led = RED_LED;

   // Check for change and update
   if (new_led != current_led) {
      digitalWrite(current_led, LOW);
      digitalWrite(new_led, HIGH);
      current_led = new_led;
   }

   // Add a few milli-seconds for debounce
   delay(20);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a decent answer, ignoring whatever "active inputs" means...

Comment: @DuncanC by active inputs i mean, a series of buttons being pressed at the same time, if there is 29 buttons then when less then 12 of them is pressed the green light would be turned on. not sure if this helps.

Comment: @oliversindahl thanks for the info. That allows an update to the answer :)